# RegEx force quantifier to be valid

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am struggling to get my regex validation for name initials to work.

I have the following code:

```
// S.P. of Sp.A. 
string voorletters = "S.P.aAa"; // This should be invalid
string regexPattern = "^([A-Z]{1}[.]|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}[.])*";
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(voorletters, regexPattern);
```

The following example should be invalid, but does match and therefore goes through.
http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=439e7c6e-ce74-4b5a-ac60-d8abeee69675

How can i force the quantifiers (*) for validation?

Comment: What do you mean by `force the quantifier`?

Comment: The quantifier at the end (the *) makes it so the next input is a repeat of the previous group. Whatever the next group is doesnt matter because the first group is validated, and IsMatch returns true. I dont want this, as i want all groups to be validated.

Comment: It would help if you provided a few examples of which strings should match and which strings shouldn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*\.)+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^([A-Z][a-z]*\.)+$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]*                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This doesn't match `S.P.Aa`.

Comment: Thank you, this solution indeed works fine. (a bit shorter aswell :)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici A dot is allways required at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]?\.)*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DoW9tjw6lZYeGF_t)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
"^([A-Z]{1}[.]|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}[.]??)*$"
```

The $ at the end is required, because in your use case, the part that was matched was actually just "S.P.". The "??" behind the second dot is optional, depending on what you want in practice - should "S.P.Aa" work or not?